# Argument of $1-z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$.
I am trying to find $\arg(1-z^2)$...

I have the following:
$1-z^2=1-r^2 \cos(2\theta) - ir^2 \sin(2\theta)$.
Then using the identities: $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos(\theta)^2 -1$ and $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$
I get,
$1-z^2=1+r^2(1-2\cos(\theta))e^{i\theta}$

This I believe this implies:
$\arg(1-z^2)=\arg(z)$.
Am I right??

Comment: Can you edit to show your work? I'm guessing there might be some mistake there

Comment: Try with a couple of numbers and see whether it makes sense. What about $z=i$, for instance? Do you have $\arg(z)=\arg(1-z^2)$ then?

Comment: What happens when $z=i$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $r=1$ so $z=e^{i\theta}$.  Even in this restricted case, the statement ${\rm arg}(1-z^2)=\theta$ fails.

If you draw a picture, marking the points $0,1$ and $z^2$ on the complex plane, you get an isosceles triangle, with $0$ as apex.

If $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ then the internal angle at $0$ is $2\theta$. Thus the other two angles are $\pi/2-\theta$.  As alternating angles are equal, we get: $${\rm arg}(1-z^2)=-(\pi/2-\theta).$$

For $\theta=\pi/2$ we get ${\rm arg}(1-z^2)=0=-(\pi/2-\theta)$.

If $\theta\in(\pi/2,\pi)$ then the internal angle at $0$ is $2\pi-2\theta$.  Thus the other two angles are $\theta-\pi/2$.   As alternating angles are equal, we get: $${\rm arg}(1-z^2)=(\theta-\pi/2).$$

For $\theta\in(\pi,2\pi)$ we have $\theta-\pi\in (0,\pi)$ and we may use the previous argument to get the argument you want as $\theta-\pi-\pi/2=\theta-3\pi/2$.

At $\theta=0,\pi$ the question is not valid.

---

So the statement ${\rm arg}(1-z^2)=\theta.$ is false.  The error in the OP's reasoning is in multiplying out:

$$(1-2\cos(\theta))e^{i\theta}=(1-2\cos(\theta))(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)).$$

The real part of this expression comes to $\cos(\theta)-2\cos^2(\theta)$, **NOT** $1-2\cos^2(\theta)$, as the OP is suggesting.

Also the imaginary part comes to $\sin(\theta)-2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, **NOT** $-2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, as the OP is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

$$w=1-z^2=1-r^2 \cos \theta- ir^2 \sin \theta \implies \\
\phi = \tan^{-1}  \left |\frac{-r^2 \sin 2\theta}{1-r^2 \cos 2\theta}\right|,  0<\phi <\pi/2, \theta= \arg z.$$ If $w$ falls in first quadrant then $\arg w= \phi$. If $w$ is in second quadrant $\arg w =\pi-\phi$. If $w$ is in third quadrant, then $\arg w= \phi -\pi.$ If $w$ is in fourth quadrant, $\arg w= -\phi.$